# Floating action button displaying on top right instead of bottom right android

Tags: android

This is my parent layout where i am including FAB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>



        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottomButtons"
            >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/floating_button"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.wokoshop.sony.app.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is actual FAB layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cart"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:elevation="6dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This FAB is displaying in top right in layout. I want to display it on bottom right.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Include it inside relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Include your FAB layout in your parent layout giving layout_alignParentBottom property true:

```
    <include layout="@layout/activity_dialog"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Also try to change CoordinatorLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Also try to change CoordinatorLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<include>` tag.

Place your FAB in its place with the `<anchor>` tag:

> app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cart"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:elevation="6dp" />
```

If you still aren't winning, revise your layout by referring to this: [FAB in the corner.](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons)